# What are the dimensions of the Windows CMD/Command Prompt?

Tags: c#, cmd

I know that the Command Prompt is 80 characters across and 300 characters down by default. Here's the difficulty: I'm trying to create a C# WinForms window that is the exact same size as the command prompt window. What width and height should I use to get the window to be the same size?

EDIT: All I'm looking for is to recreate the size of the command prompt window with a C# WinForms window. What width/height should I use?

Comment: 80*300 is the size of the virtual terminal, while the default size of the window itself is 80*25 (and this value, BTW, is not fixed and can be changed).

Comment: What is your question really. Be precise.

Comment: There is no exclusive size for console windows.  Beyond the window size, the font size is configurable too in the shortcut properties.  Create a shortcut to cmd.exe on your desktop to see this for yourself.

Answer (score 21):

Default window size should be 80x25. Default buffer size is 80x300.

Comment: unless the user changes the defaults

Answer (score 2):

If you have a console process you can call GetConsoleWindow and then GetWindowRect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run cmd, take a screenshot, paste the image into an image editor, cut the cmd window, paste it into its own image and then view the size of the new image.  That will give you the x and y lengths in pixels.

Comment: There's always GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo

Answer (score 1):

The default command prompt dimensions are 677, 343. The height being 677 and the width being 343, hope this helps.